# Why does TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32 doesn't work alone?

Tags: c, winapi

I was experimenting with some stuff in WinAPI. My OS is Win7 x64 P1 Ultimate. When I was trying to list all modules of a process I found out that the module that I wanted is a 32-bit module so I replaced

```
TH32CS_SNAPMODULE
```

With

```
TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32
```

After this no module was shown. So I decided to try using bitwise operators and looks like if I send the arguments like this

```
TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32 | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE
```

It works perfectly fine, listing all 64bit and 32bit modules. So my question here is why it doesn't work alone? Even the docs say it **can** be used with `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE`.

Quote from MSDN

> TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32
>
> Includes all 32-bit modules of the process specified in th32ProcessID in the snapshot when called from a 64-bit process. This flag can be combined with TH32CS_SNAPMODULE or TH32CS_SNAPALL. If the function fails with ERROR_BAD_LENGTH, retry the function until it succeeds.

Comment: Sounds like the documentation is wrong (or at least poorly worded).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is admittedly confusing. What it meant to say is that the `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` flag *must* be combined with another flag, but *can only* be combined with `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE` or `TH32CS_SNAPALL`.

It's only slightly better phrased in this official answer [TH32CS_SNAPMODULE vs TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/fUheCca7pv4/2bndZyO_I9oJ) - note the "**extra**":

> Based on the feedback from the developer team, TH32CS_SNAPMODULE will 
>   provide you native modules.  You can OR TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32 with 
>   TH32CS_SNAPMODULE to get 32-bit modules also when on a 64-bit box.  It 
>   exists to indicate that you want the **extra** 32-bit module state.